# Hierarchical Query Child Override

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical company structure where each company has an optional company sector.  Child companies inherit their parent's sector if they don't have their own, but the child company sector overrides its parent's if the child one.

I need to produce a sum of the bill amount grouped by sector.  Companies with no sector are ignored.

The ParentCompanyID column in the Company table is a foreign key to itself.  There can be an unlimited number of parent/child levels.

**Company Table**

```
CompanyID ParentCompanyID
   1           null
   2            1
   3            2
   4           null
   5            4
   6           null
   7            6
   8            7
```

**CompanySector Table**

```
CompanyID    Sector
    1     Distribution
    4     Distribution
    5     Manufacturing
    8     Manufacturing
```

**Timesheet Table**

```
CompanyID  BillAmount
    1        100
    1        200
    2        100
    3        50
    4        25
    5        75
    6        75
    7        115
    8        115
```

The result I expect to see here is:

```
   Sector      BillAmount 
Distribution      475
Manufacturing     190
```

Below is how I am currently doing it.  It is extremely inefficient and doesn't work for unlimited number of hierarchical levels.

```
WITH Company AS
  ( SELECT 1 CompanyID, NULL ParentCompanyID FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2, 1 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3, 2 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4, NULL FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 5, 4 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 6, NULL FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 7, 6 FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 8, 7 FROM dual
  ),
  CompanySector AS
  ( SELECT 1 CompanyID, 'Distribution' Sector FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4 , 'Distribution' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 5 , 'Manufacturing' FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 8 , 'Manufacturing' FROM dual
  ),
  Timesheets AS
  ( SELECT 1 CompanyID, 100 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 1 CompanyID, 200 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 CompanyID, 100 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3 CompanyID, 50 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4 CompanyID, 25 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 5 CompanyID, 75 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 6 CompanyID, 75 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 7 CompanyID, 115 BillAmount FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 8 CompanyID, 115 BillAmount FROM dual
  ),

  --Dummy tables above
  --My current way of doing it below
  companies AS
  (SELECT c.*,
    cs.sector
  FROM company c
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanySector cs
  ON c.companyID = cs.companyID
  ),
  sectors AS
  (SELECT levelOne.companyID,
    NVL(levelOne.sector, NVL(levelTwo.sector, NVL(levelThree.sector, NULL))) sector
  FROM companies levelOne
  LEFT OUTER JOIN companies levelTwo
  ON levelOne.parentcompanyid = levelTwo.companyID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN companies levelThree
  ON levelTwo.parentcompanyid                                                     = levelThree.companyID
  WHERE NVL(levelOne.sector, NVL(levelTwo.sector, NVL(levelThree.sector, NULL))) IS NOT NULL
  )
SELECT s.sector,
  SUM(t.billamount)
FROM sectors s
INNER JOIN timesheets t
ON s.companyID = t.companyID
GROUP BY sector;
```

What is a cleaner and more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do it.  Using the hierarchical query syntax, populate sector from the parent record where needed.

```
WITH
  base_sectors AS (
  SELECT * FROM company LEFT OUTER JOIN companySector USING (companyID)
  )
, final_sectors AS (
  SELECT companyID, NVL( sector, PRIOR sector ) AS sector
  FROM base_sectors
  START WITH parentCompanyID IS NULL
  CONNECT BY parentCompanyID = PRIOR companyID
)
SELECT s.sector,
  SUM(t.billamount)
FROM final_sectors s
INNER JOIN timesheets t
ON s.companyID = t.companyID
GROUP BY sector;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, this is very close but I think a piece is missing here.  It's only including companies that have an exact link to a companysector.  For instance, companies 2 and 3 are not inheriting the sector from company 1, their parent company.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, that first join should be an outer join.  Updated!

Comment: No apology needed!  This is sooooo close.  I don't think I explained correctly that children should inherit sectors all the way up until it finds a non null value, not just from their direct parent.  So company 3 should pull the sector from two levels up (company 1).  In your query company 3 has a null sector.  I'm fiddling with it and can't quite get it.

Comment: Try replacing the `NVL` expression with `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(sector,'/')`.  That should give you a string with the sector values from all ancestor records.  Then hopefully you can parse out the last non-NULL value.

Comment: I went with REGEXP_SUBSTR(trim(trailing '.' FROM SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(sector,'.')), '[^.]+$') AS sector   This is exactly what I was looking for.  The efficiency is up for debate, but it's cleaner than what I had.  Thanks!